# How do I create a Vim function-list inside quick-fix window?

Tags: vim, ctags

Is there a way to put all functions defined in the current buffer to the quick-fix list? Imagine `Tlist` (from `taglist` plugin) opened in quick-fix window.

Comment: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Putting-all-ctags-matches-into-quickfix-td1182150.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an expression that returns the list that you want. Eg:

   ```
   let cmd='exctags -x '.bufname('%')." | awk '{print $4\"|\"$3\"|\",$1}'"
   ```
2. Feed it to `cexpr` or `cgetexpr`

   ```
   cexpr system(cmd)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is using [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) for Vim. It also requires ctags but offers buffer listing/jumping, FuzzyFinder like file open. With outline plugin, you have a nice function listing. I use it all the time not only for jumping to function definition but also for a quick look up at arguments.

[image: http://cl.ly/5xok/ss-13042011.png]

Comment: Could you explain with detail how you get this with unite? Thanks.

Comment: Alright. After install `ctags`, [Unite.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim), and [Unite Outline plugin](https://github.com/h1mesuke/unite-outline), you can open any supported file type (See [http://d.hatena.ne.jp/h1mesuke/20101107/p1] I don't speak Japanese but the screenshots are enough), fire `:Unite outline` and you will get the popup buffer with nice outline like the ss. At this point you can use `<c-n>`, `<c-p>` or just type a few character to get the list filtered. Hit enter will jump to the selected function/header. One draw back is that this is limited in a file.

Comment: How did you get it to open in a vertical split like that?  I can only seem to open it horizontally-above.  I looked in the code, but am not that deep in Vim yet

Comment: I see now that Unite 'core' handles this setting. Use `-vertical or -horizontal`. [See all variables here](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/blob/e0233e68c031e434868767a9e6279aa754ff251b/autoload/unite/variables.vim#L175). e.g. I now use `nnoremap <space>o :Unite -start-insert -vertical -winwidth=50 -direction=belowright outline` to neatly open the tag split on the right without modifying other split sizes.